# PyMC3 hangs after completing NUTS sampling

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano, python-multiprocessing, pymc3

I have a model that seems to run smoothly. I initialize my nuts sampler with a metropolis sample, and the metropolis sample completes without trouble. It then moves into the nuts sampler, completes all iterations, but then hangs.

I have tried:

- Restarting the kernel
- Clearing my theano cache
- Rebooting the computer and restarting the docker it runs in
- Metropolis sampling with multiple chains does complete and then terminate.
- Changing the seed or model specification slightly makes the model terminate *sometimes*.

But since it's not erroring out, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. When I interrupt the process, it's always stuck in the same place. The output is pasted below. 
Any help diagnosing the problem would be much appreciated.

Code for my sample is here:

```
with my_model:
    start_trace = pm.sample(7000,step=pm.Metropolis())
start_sds = {}
nms = start_trace.varnames
for i in nms:
    start_sds[i]=start_trace[i].std()
with my_model:
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=my_model.dict_to_array(start_sds)**2,
                   is_cov=True)
    signal_trace = pm.sample(500,step=step,start=start_trace[-1],njobs=3)
```

It finishes sampling. The first progress bar is for the metropolis sample, the second for NUTS:

```
100%|██████████| 7000/7000 [00:09<00:00, 718.51it/s]
100%|██████████| 500/500 [01:37<00:00,  1.47s/it]
```

Looking at top, there are four processes, each using about the same amount of memory, but only one of them is using a cpu. Usually, when it terminates properly, it ends about the time the other 3 processes stop using cpu. The fact that these other processes stop suggests that it has finished sampling, and the issue has something to do with terminating the multi-processing.

It sits until I interrupt, (I've left it over night), and I get the following error:

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkPoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/pool.py", line 362, in get
    return recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/pool.py", line 360, in get
    racquire()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 416, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/pool.py", line 360, in get
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    698                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 699                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    700                 else:

/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    592     def get(self, timeout=None):
--> 593         self.wait(timeout)
    594         if not self.ready():

/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in wait(self, timeout)
    589     def wait(self, timeout=None):
--> 590         self._event.wait(timeout)
    591 

/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    552             if not signaled:
--> 553                 signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
    554             return signaled

/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    289             if timeout is None:
--> 290                 waiter.acquire()
    291                 gotit = True

KeyboardInterrupt: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-cad95f434ae5> in <module>()
     87         step = pm.NUTS(scaling=my_model.dict_to_array(start_sds)**2,
     88                        is_cov=True)
---> 89         signal_trace = pm.sample(500,step=step,start=start_trace[-1],njobs=3)
     90 
     91     pr = forestplot(signal_trace[-500:],

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.py in sample(draws, step, init, n_init, start, trace, chain, njobs, tune, progressbar, model, random_seed)
    173         sample_func = _sample
    174 
--> 175     return sample_func(**sample_args)
    176 
    177 

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.py in _mp_sample(**kwargs)
    322                                                      random_seed=rseed[i],
    323                                                      start=start_vals[i],
--> 324                                                      **kwargs) for i in range(njobs))
    325     return merge_traces(traces)
    326 

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    787                 # consumption.
    788                 self._iterating = False
--> 789             self.retrieve()
    790             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    791             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    719                     # scheduling.
    720                     ensure_ready = self._managed_backend
--> 721                     backend.abort_everything(ensure_ready=ensure_ready)
    722 
    723                 if not isinstance(exception, TransportableException):

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in abort_everything(self, ensure_ready)
    143     def abort_everything(self, ensure_ready=True):
    144         """Shutdown the pool and restart a new one with the same parameters"""
--> 145         self.terminate()
    146         if ensure_ready:
    147             self.configure(n_jobs=self.parallel.n_jobs, parallel=self.parallel,

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in terminate(self)
    321     def terminate(self):
    322         """Shutdown the process or thread pool"""
--> 323         super(MultiprocessingBackend, self).terminate()
    324         if self.JOBLIB_SPAWNED_PROCESS in os.environ:
    325             del os.environ[self.JOBLIB_SPAWNED_PROCESS]

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in terminate(self)
    134         if self._pool is not None:
    135             self._pool.close()
--> 136             self._pool.terminate()  # terminate does a join()
    137             self._pool = None
    138 

/opt/ds/lib/python3.4/site-packages/joblib/pool.py in terminate(self)
    604         for i in range(n_retries):
    605             try:
--> 606                 super(MemmapingPool, self).terminate()
    607                 break
    608             except OSError as e:

/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in terminate(self)
    494         self._state = TERMINATE
    495         self._worker_handler._state = TERMINATE
--> 496         self._terminate()
    497 
    498     def join(self):

/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/util.py in __call__(self, wr, _finalizer_registry, sub_debug, getpid)
    183                 sub_debug('finalizer calling %s with args %s and kwargs %s',
    184                           self._callback, self._args, self._kwargs)
--> 185                 res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    186             self._weakref = self._callback = self._args = \
    187                             self._kwargs = self._key = None

/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in _terminate_pool(cls, taskqueue, inqueue, outqueue, pool, worker_handler, task_handler, result_handler, cache)
    524 
    525         util.debug('helping task handler/workers to finish')
--> 526         cls._help_stuff_finish(inqueue, task_handler, len(pool))
    527 
    528         assert result_handler.is_alive() or len(cache) == 0

/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in _help_stuff_finish(inqueue, task_handler, size)
    509         # task_handler may be blocked trying to put items on inqueue
    510         util.debug('removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished')
--> 511         inqueue._rlock.acquire()
    512         while task_handler.is_alive() and inqueue._reader.poll():
    513             inqueue._reader.recv()

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Here's the model that most consistently fails:

```
with pm.Model() as twitter_signal:
        #location fixed effects
        mu_c = pm.Flat('mu_c')
        sig_c = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_c',beta=2.5)
        c_raw = pm.Normal('c_raw',mu=0,sd=1,shape=n_location)
        c = pm.Deterministic('c',mu_c + sig_c*c_raw)

        #time fixed effects
        mu_t = pm.Flat('mu_t')
        sig_t = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_t',beta=2.5)
        t_raw = pm.Normal('t_raw',mu=0,sd=1,shape=n_time)
        t = pm.Deterministic('t',mu_t + sig_t*t_raw)

        #signal effect 
        b_sig = pm.Normal('b_sig',0,sd=100**2,shape=1)    

        #control
        b_control = pm.Normal('b_control',mu=0,sd=100**2,shape=1)

    # define linear model and link function

        #y_hat
        theta =c[df.location.values] + \
            t[df.dates.values] + \
            (b_sig[df.c.values]* df.sig.values) + \
            (b_death[df.c.values]*df.control.values)

        disp = pm.HalfCauchy('disp',beta=2.5)    

        ## Define likelihood
        y = pm.NegativeBinomial('y', mu=np.exp(theta),
                        alpha=disp, 
                        observed=df.loc[:,yvar])
```

Comment: Is that reproducible (and if so, could you share the setup?)  
The progress bar only reflects one of the jobs, so either of the other two might be getting stuck here –  I think it would be possible to have one per process, but no one has done that work.  From what you've described it does not sound like that is the problem anyway...

Comment: I haven't done it with simulation data yet, but it does depend on model specification. Even changing the seed can make a model that wouldn't terminate terminate. I don't *think* it's that one of the chains is stuck, because the processes all end, and it seems to get stuck shutting down the multiprocessing, but it could be that it's the remaining process. I don't think it's an issue with my system because it terminates sometimes, and Metropolis terminates without trouble.
It's a hierarchical model. Having categories with lots of zeros seems to make it more likely to happen, but only sometimes.

Comment: I've put the model specification above. When I get a chance I'll try to see if I can narrow down a reproducible example with simulation data.